# Linkstyle in pdflatex

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

What are the different styles to mark a link within the document (not necessarily limited to `hyperref`)

What I have till now:

- Ugly box around : `\usepackage{hyperref}`
- Different color : `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`

It should be for pdflatex and if platform dependent then for Linux.

It should produce links for at least:

- `\tableofcontents`
- glossaries
- bibtex

Answer (score 7):

The link border style can also be configured to some degree, from `hyperref`'s [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf):

> ### Link border style
>
> Links can be underlined instead of the default rectangle or
>   options "colorlinks", "frenchlinks". This is done by option
>         pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
>
> Some remarks:
>
> - AR7/Linux seems to have a bug, that don't use the default
>     value "1" for the width, but zero, thus that the underline
>     is not visible without "/W 1". The same applies for
>     dashed boxes, eg.:
>       pdfborderstyle={/S/D/D[3 2]/W 1}
> - The syntax is described in the PDF specification, look for
>     "border style", eg.
>     Table 8.13 "Entries in a border style dictionary"
>     (specification for version 1.6)
> - The border style is removed by
>       pdfborderstyle={}
>     This is automatically done if option colorlinks is enabled.
> - Be aware that not all PDF viewers support this feature, not
>     even Acrobat Reader itself:
>
>   Some support:
>
>   - AR7/Linux: "underline" and "dashed", but the border width
>       must be given.
>   - xpdf 3.00: "underline" and "dashed"
>
>   Unsupported:
>
>   - AR5/Linux
>   - ghostscript 8.50

There is also option `frenchlinks`, but I do not know, whether this option is used by anyone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't use the pdfborderstyles till now. The limited support puts me off a bit here. But something it's defenetly something in this dirrection I'm looking for.